# Why is the size of video less than the size of its individual frames?

Tags: image, video, frames, split

I have a small video. Its size on disk is 635 Kb. It is in .avi format. It has 3004 frames in it. All the frames are almost similar. When I save individual frame, each frame is 935bytes. So, the size of video should be at least

3004*935 bytes = 2.6Mb. But why the video is only 635 Kb??

I have all these 3004 images in a variable of datatype cell in matlab. The size of that variable is around 6.5 Mb, but the sum of all the sizes of individual images is only 2.5 Mb. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: compression.  Since many of the pixels are the same from one frame to the next, compression algorithms can work efficiently on video data, instead of repeatedly storing much of the redundant information.